# Hadoop IntWritable Iterable retrieve value by index?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a Iterable Object.To convert a IntWriter to int we can use get() method.Is there a way to retrieve the first value of an Iterable Intwriter object.I tried

```
Iterator<IntWritable> values;
values.get(0).get() //To retrieve the first value.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Guava:

```
Iterable<IntWritable> iterable = ...;
int first = Iterables.get(iterable, 0).get();
```

Or Java8:

```
int value = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).findFirst().get().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
Iterator<IntWriteable> itr = iterable.iterator();
 while (itr.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(itr.next().get());
   break;
 }
```

Comment: Nope I am asking about hadoop datatype IntWritable not String I know about strings.Thanks.

Comment: Does that makes sense now?

Comment: Yeah but my question was different I want to get the first element at index 0 without using iterator.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get();
        }
        // big 2
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
```